# Just one more thing

Tags: discussion, unaccepted-answer

This is getting old, sometimes I answer a Q and it feels like doing tech support for my uncle or neighbor. You know, they call every few days with "one more thing".

Case: [Reset a list using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237905/reset-a-list-using-jquery/17237995)

Here, they accept an answer and thank you for the help, then come back the next day, take back the 15 rep, and change the question scope in the comments.

How can I reply to comments like this better in the future? Any suggestions on kindly asking the OP to just make a new question rather than appointing me as their personal help desk?

Comment: These are sometimes known as ["chameleon" questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), and this is related to the  ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?lq=1).

Comment: That question hasn't actually been edited. You're still +60 on that answer even if you choose to ignore the OP's change of tack and move on.

Comment: Oh, the question wasn't edited. The scope changed in the comments of my answer. Which makes it even more confusing to future visitors.

Comment: Thank you Josh, I couldn't figure out a google query to find the duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you ended up doing is the right thing.

The only way I've found to work in tackling these "just one more thing" users is to tell them this is *not* accepted behavior here and that they should open a new question with their new problem.

Another thing. When I see these scenarios I usually [leave a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170866/making-a-vector-of-graphs-in-lemon-graph-library#comment24862735_17171180) explaining the issue.

> Hi, generally follow up questions are usually frowned upon here. If this answer solved your problem and answered your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). If you have other questions please consider asking them in a new thread instead of adding 'follow up' questions here. Not only are such follow up questions frustrating for the answer giver, they also make it impossible to others with the same problem solve their issue...

I usually try to edit that into something that's more case-specific. I always try to stay positive and friendly towards the OP. It's *especially* useful when it's not *my* answer - I think that affirms that it's considered bad by *the community* rather than the specific user who gave the answer.

Edit: I just left one [such comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17237905/reset-a-list-using-jquery/17237995#comment25008417_17237995) on your answer. I hope it helps :)

Edit2: Looks like you got your happy ending, I hope this is some indication that this method is useful - at least to an extent.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. One more thing, can you also do something about that Close Votes Queue?

Comment: Not sure if "one more thing" is supposed to be ironic but made me laugh anyway...